# How do I add a record on the basis of another record exist in other table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm adding a row on the basis of userid and mapping id. If it exists, it will not take similar entry again and if it does not exist, it will be added.

This is my code:

```
SET @mappingId = (SELECT id 
                  FROM Mapping_Links_Clients_Instances 
                  WHERE Client_ID = @clientId AND Instance_ID= @tenantId)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM implementation 
               WHERE [MappingId] = @mappingId AND [UserId] = @UserId)
    INSERT INTO Implementation ([ImplementationName], [LastUpdate],[UserId], [MappingId], [UserName])
    VALUES (@implementationName, GETDATE(), @UserId, @mappingId, @UserName)
```

But I want to add another feature which is if the mappingid is not there in the other table then also it will not make any entry

Comment: sorry for the inconveinience.. yes you are right. edited the tag

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as a single INSERT .. SELECT statement

```
insert into Implementation ([ImplementationName],[LastUpdate],[UserId],[MappingId],[UserName])
select @implementationName, GETDATE(), @UserId, @mappingId, @UserName
where NOT EXISTS(
  select 1 
  from implementation i
  join Mapping_Links_Clients_Instances m 
    on i.[MappingId] = m.id 
       and m.Client_ID = @clientId 
       and m.Instance_ID = @tenantId 
       and i.[UserId] = @UserId
  )
```

Now you can add more conditions at will. Probably add one more join

```
insert into Implementation ([ImplementationName],[LastUpdate],[UserId],[MappingId],[UserName])
select @implementationName, GETDATE(), @UserId, @mappingId, @UserName
where NOT EXISTS(
  select 1 
  from implementation i
  join Mapping_Links_Clients_Instances m 
    on i.[MappingId] = m.id 
       and m.Client_ID = @clientId 
       and m.Instance_ID = @tenantId 
       and i.[UserId] = @UserId
   join anotherTable t 
     on ..
  )
```

Comment: but still the data is getting added with mappingid  0 which i dont want.